# How to initialize redis with cached data

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-boot, redis

I have a service built with `spring boot` and `redis`, which listens for `HTTP` requests.

I would like that when the server runs up, it populates some predefined data in redis cache.

I thought about having a `.yml` file and when the service starts it calls an endpoint like `/addData` with the information of that `.yml` file; but I think this is not an efficient way to achieve my goal.

Which is the best option to start a service with data cached in `redis`?

Answer (score 1):

2 options either EventListener or on the main method

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void loadRedis() {
    //do the work here
}
```

another option is to do it in springbootapplication main method.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
 SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    context.getBean(Whatever.class).loadRedis();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using JedisPool

```
public static void initCache() {
   jedisPool = new JedisPool( new JedisPoolConfig() , "localhost",8081);

 }
```